# No mouse and wireless on Ubuntu 14.04 after full battery discharge

Tags: 14.04, boot, drivers

After I returned with charger after an hour and booted dead laptop (Lenovo T430), first noticed my trusted wireless USB mouse was dead, after logging in I was greeted with "Software rendering mode" and finally no wireless adapter - just cable option. Looks like driver is not loaded at all.

Before bleeding the battery dry everything was fine. That's so strange, as I had hard reset this laptop several times.

I suppose some module loading config went down, how could I restore? Linux kernel 3.13

Comment: I had once landed in such a situation. I was doing battery calibration and I force drained the battery. After reboot, oh, broken system :( Had to reinstall :((